# Navbar change Color using Observer

Tags: javascript, css

Hey out there reading,

i'm making a webpage and im relativly new to JavaScript. I want the Navbar to change Color when its in section Two, while in Section One and Three the Navbar should have the same Color. I watched some tutorials and was able with that code to change the color of the navbar so that in section one and section two the navbar has the right color. When trying out the variables sectionTwo and sectionThree (in order to get the navbars Color to switch back to the color in sectionOne when entering sectionThree) on the other hand it didnt change the colors at the right position (like 100px befor the section). I dont know why this problem accures. If someone knows how to fix it, it would mean the world to me :).

```js
const header = document.querySelector("header")
const sectionOne = document.querySelector(".one")
const sectionTwo = document.querySelector(".two")
const sectionThree = document.querySelector(".three")

const sectionOneOptions = {
    
}

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, sectionOneObserver) {   
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            header.classList.add("nav-scrolled")
        } else {
            header.classList.remove("nav-scrolled")
        }
    });
},
sectionOneOptions);

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionTwo)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Arial";
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
header {
  --text: #fff;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8rem;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 0 1rem 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
header nav {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header nav li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px, 15px;
  color: var(--text);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.nav-scrolled {
  --text: #000;
}
.one {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 200px 20vw;
  display: flex;
}
.two {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px 20vw;
  background: #fff;
}
.three {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px 20vw;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
      <div class="one" id="one"></div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="two" id="two"></div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="three" id="three"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need some more Code and not only the snippet to fix this.
Hopefully some hero can help me :).

Greetings

Noel

Comment: Could you put in example HTML so we can see the problem for ourselves. And what does the nav scrolled class do?

Comment: @AHaworth Sure will add. 'Noel

Comment: @AHaworth i also added a full CSS that you are able to see the problem yourself fast :)

Comment: Where do you observe section2 and section3? Also can you cut out any extraneous code and make a working snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for the advice and help tried to delete as much as possible extraneouse code and transformed it into a working snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did research to try and answer this question, so please take the preface that I am not an expert in `IntersectionObserver`.

With that preface out of the way,

There were many things I changed from your example to create the desired effect, however the core feature that you would have needed to implement in your example is the option for intersection observers, `rootMargin`. By adding this option you can give the item on the screen a negative top and bottom margin. This is important, because you do not want the observer to fire until the header is about to cross into the observed section, and you dont want the header to change until just before it crosses back into the next section.

The way I chose to emulate this behavior, is by using the rootMargin option to give a negative margin. This makes the actual element observed begin however many pixels after we specify. For example, an element that is 100px in height, with `"0px 0px -20px 0px"` as the value for `rootMargin` in the options object, would not trigger the IntersectionObserver until 20px of the element was scrolled into the viewport height.

With this understanding, we can define our goal. We want to preform an action when the observed element is about to touch the header. We can describe this as the viewport height minus the header height in a negative margin to the bottom would adjust the element just enough to trigger the intersection observer as desired. Because the methods of obtaining margins are not exact, I subtract one from the numbers calculated to adjust for small error. If we set both margins to overlap eachother, we will never have the observer fire.

I also decided to use css variables and set the value of the variable depending on whether or not the element observed scrolled into or out of the viewport.

This code is not able to execute properly in a stack snippet because the viewport option that the intersection observer defaults to in the options is not set correctly for the snippet environment. I have not tested this code in environments that resize.

Hopefully that explanation helps you understand this code. Let me know if you have any questions.

relevant html:

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="one">
</section>
<section id="two">
</section>
<section id="three">
</section>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

relevant css:

```css
:root {
  --header-text-color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header a {
  color: var(--header-text-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  height: 120vh;
  background: black;
}

#two {
  background: white;
}
```

relevant js:

```js
const header = document.querySelector("header");
const sectionTwo = document.querySelector("#two");

const topMargin = header.offsetHeight - 1;
const bottomMargin = window.innerHeight - header.offsetHeight - 1;

const options = {
  rootMargin: `-${topMargin}px 0px -${bottomMargin}px 0px`,
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  const color = entry.isIntersecting ? "black" : "white";
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--header-text-color', color);
}, options);

observer.observe(sectionTwo);
```